# EventListener for swipe inside modal fail to update the image

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, event-listener

I have a webpage with a couple of images. When the images are clicked they open in a modal. Inside the modal there are 2 buttons, previous and next. When these are clicked the image change as expected. The problem is when I try to add swipe gestures for mobile. I have add the eventListeners for that and configured correctly the logic. If swipe to right the prev button is clicked and if to left the next. I have checked and the modalImg.src is updated yet the image does not change.

Inside my ImgEnlarge function for the modal I have:

Initialisation:

```
// Get the modal
            var modal = document.getElementById(modal);

            // Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
            var img = document.getElementById(img_id);
            var modalImg = document.getElementById("work-img");
            var captionText = document.getElementById(caption);
            var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img'); 
            var srcList = [];
            var altList = [];
            for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
                if (images[i].src.toString().includes('paintings')) {
                    srcList.push(images[i].src);
                    altList.push(images[i].alt);
                }
            }
```

Buttons - functions:

```
function updateImage(img_src) {
                //document.write(modalImg.src, captionText.innerHTML);
                modalImg.src = img_src;
                captionText.innerHTML = altList[srcList.indexOf(index)]
                //img = modalImg.src
                //document.write(modalImg.src, captionText.innerHTML);
            }
            
            img.onclick = function(){
                modal.style.display = "block";
                modalImg.src = this.src;
                captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
                /* disable scrolling */
                document.documentElement.style.overflow = 'hidden';
                document.body.scroll = "no";
            }

            // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
            var close = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

            // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
            close.onclick = function() {
                modal.style.display = "none";
                /* enable scrolling */
                document.documentElement.style.overflow = 'scroll';
                document.body.scroll = "yes";
            }
            // Get the <span> element that opens image full-screen
            var fullscreen = document.getElementsByClassName("fullscreen-button")[0];

            // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
            fullscreen.onclick = function() {
                //Use the specification method before using prefixed versions
                if (modalImg.requestFullscreen) {
                    modalImg.requestFullscreen();
                } else if (modalImg.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Safari */
                    modalImg.webkitRequestFullscreen();
                } else if (modalImg.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE11 */
                    modalImg.msRequestFullscreen();
                }
            }
            // click image to open in fullscreen
            modalImg.onclick = function(){
                fullscreen.click();
            }

            // Get the <span> element that goes to the next image
            var next = document.getElementsByClassName("next")[0];
            next.onclick = function() {
                this_img_index = srcList.indexOf(modalImg.src);
                if (this_img_index == srcList.length-1){
                    next_img = srcList[0];
                } else {
                    next_img = srcList[this_img_index+1];
                }
                updateImage(next_img);
                
            }

            // Get the <span> element that goes to the previous image
            var prev = document.getElementsByClassName("prev")[0];
            prev.onclick = function() {
                this_img_index = srcList.indexOf(modalImg.src);
                if (this_img_index == 0){
                    prev_img = srcList[srcList.length-1];
                } else {
                    prev_img = srcList[this_img_index-1];
                }
                //modalImg.src = prev_img;
                //captionText.innerHTML = altList[srcList.indexOf(prev_img)];
                updateImage(prev_img);
            }

            // Get the input field
            var input = document.getElementById("myInput");
            document.onkeydown = checkKey;
            function checkKey(e) {
                e = e || window.event;
                //
                if (e.keyCode == '37') {
                    // left arrow
                    prev.click();
                } else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
                    // right arrow
                    next.click();
                } else if (e.keyCode == '27') {
                    //escape
                    close.click();
                }
            }
```

And EventListeners:

```
                var touchStartX;
            var touchEndX;
            const minSwipeDistance = 50; // Minimum swipe distance threshold
            // calculate starting point
            function handleTouchStart(event) {
                touchStartX = event.touches[0].clientX;
            }
            // calculate ending point
            function handleTouchMove(event) {
                touchEndX = event.touches[0].clientX;
            }
            function handleTouchEnd() {
                const swipeDistance = touchStartX - touchEndX;
                if (swipeDistance < -minSwipeDistance) {
                    // Swipe to previous
                    prev.click();
                } else if (swipeDistance > minSwipeDistance){
                    // Swipe to next
                    var next = document.getElementsByClassName("next")[0];
                    next.click();
                    //document.write(modalImg.src);
                    //captionText.innerHTML = altList[srcList.indexOf(index)];
                    //document.write(modalImg.src);
                }
            }
            // Attach touch event listeners to the image element
            modal.addEventListener('touchstart', function handleTouchStart(event) {
                touchStartX = event.touches[0].clientX;
            });
            modal.addEventListener('touchmove', function handleTouchMove(event) {
                touchEndX = event.touches[0].clientX;
            });
            modal.addEventListener('touchend',  function(){ handleTouchEnd(); });
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: I strongly recommend delegation and only have one event listener that reacts to each set of events, like click and touchstart for example

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks! Unfortunately it doesnt seem to work... i really dont get how updating the modalImg.src does not change the image when initialized from the eventlistener. Shouldnt it work just like an input from the keyboard? I dont really get why this is complicated to implement tbh.

Comment: Please do what I ask. Click [edit] then the `[<>]` snippet editor button and make a [mcve]